# Any time you should use relative links for internal pages?

Tags: html, hyperlink

So, I know some software (like KompoZer, and probably some CMSs) will use relative links when linking to pages on the same site. Whereas, say you're writing a post with your free Blogger blog and you link to an older post, you're probably going to use an absolute link (because you just navigated to the old post and copied its full URI).

So, what I'm really asking is, should you pay much attention to using relative links when appropriate? Or are there tools to make changing the URIs around when you so need that negate that habit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work in something like a Development-Preview-Production environment, you will find testing much easier if you use relative links. Otherwise, clicking on a link on the development server will take you to the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use absolute links when using Blogger? Relative links are preferred any time you can use them. Tools are useful when the link format changes, but why introduce complexity otherwise? Not much is easier than "copy it from here to there; done."

Comment: My bad, I should of explained. For the less OCD among us (also known as casual bloggers), you might just navigate to the previous post you wanted to reference, copy the full URI, and then link with that.

Comment: "*...the less OCD among us...*" - LOL!